# Adding cookies on this script

Tags: jquery, cookies

Can somebody add cookies on this code ? It's for a theme changer.. :P

```
$(function () {
    $("ul.rightside").prepend('<div id="nav_background">Colors</div>');
    $(".minwidth_IE").prepend('<div id="toggle_background" style="display: none;"><div id="navigation_popup_close" class="popupClose clickable"><img src="http://i81.servimg.com/u/f81/18/07/42/17/close_11.png" alt="x"></div><div id="custom_background"><span id="bg0"></span><span id="bg1"></span><span id="bg2"></span><span id="bg3"></span><span id="bg4"></span><span id="bg5"></span><span id="bg7"></span><span id="bg8"></span></div></div>');
    $("#custom_background span").click(function () {
        $("#account ,.minwidth_IE ,.main .main-head ,#fa_toolbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom").addClass($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    $("#custom_submit").click(function () {
        var b = $("#custom_input").val();
        $("#account ,.minwidth_IE ,.main .main-head ,#fa_toolbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom").addClass("bg_custom").css("background-image", "url('" + b + "')");
    });
    $("#nav_background").click(function () {
        $("#toggle_background").slideToggle();
    });
    $("#navigation_popup_close").click(function() {
   $("#toggle_background").fadeOut();
});

 $("#custom_background span").click(function () {
        $("#vbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom bg11 bg21 bg31 bg41 bg51 bg71 bg81").addClass($(this).attr("id")+ (+1));
    });
    $("#custom_submit").click(function () {
        var b = $("#custom_input").val();
        $("#vbar").removeClass("bg11 bg21 bg31 bg41 bg51 bg71 bg81 bg_custom2").addClass("bg_custom2").css("background-image", "url('" + b + "')");
    });

$("#custom_background span").click(function () {
        $("#tbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom bg12 bg22 bg32 bg42 bg52 bg72 bg82").addClass($(this).attr("id")+ (+2));
    });
    $("#custom_submit").click(function () {
        var b = $("#custom_input").val();
        $("#tbar").removeClass("bg12 bg22 bg32 bg42 bg52 bg72 bg82 bg_custom3").addClass("bg_custom3").css("background-image", "url('" + b + "')");
    });

 $("#bg0").click(function(){
 $("#account ,.minwidth_IE ,.main .main-head ,#fa_toolbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom");
  $("#vbar").removeClass("bg11 bg21 bg31 bg41 bg51 bg71 bg81 bg_custom2");
  $("#tbar").removeClass("bg12 bg22 bg32 bg42 bg52 bg72 bg82 bg_custom3");
});
});
```

Hope someone know how to add on this code cookies without any bug. Thank you very much again!

Comment: I assume you want to have cookies save the user's chosen theme. I would suggest adding a function activate_theme(theme_name) which sets the cookie and then makes the necessary modifications. on page load you can fetch the cookie and adjust accordingly, also see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp . at the moment your code   (and question) is not so easily understandable unless taking the time.

Comment: Cookies are way to store data in user's browser. What kind of data do you want to store there? The code you posted is jquery, what in the world it use cookies for? Your question doesnt even makes sense. And if it did, this is not place to get your code done for free, you have to try on your own, and if you get stuck after hours of trying and failing, looking for other answers, reading manuals and `duckduckgo`ing solutions to your problems, *then* post a question here, together with the stuff you tried. But anyway, adding cookies to this jquery makes little sense to me.

Comment: Ah now I see why cookies, you want to store the setting in the browser. That makes sense, but still, you should try it yourself.

@Filou note that w3schools.com is really bad reference. It's not affiliated with w3c in any way, it belongs to some scandinavian family that's just exploiting nice domain address.

Comment: Oh, I did not know, thanks for the note!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for jQuery called `jquery.cookie` that makes working with cookies a breeze.

You just need to download the plugin and include it with the following line:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Then work with it like so:

**Setting a cookie**

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

**Reading a cookie**

```
var theValue = $.cookie('the_cookie');
```

For more information see:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme

Comment: So, can you please make the code for me ? I'm newbie with Javascript.. lol.. :(

Comment: I'm sorry I can't write your code for you, I can only point you in the right direction. The answer above shows you how to set and retrieve a value. You just need to figure out what value you need to save, and when you need to load it again :)

Comment: @user2816226 You haven't understood what this site is for: It's for programming problems, not a service where people are coding for you.

Comment: Ohh.. i have this code.. but.. i think it's not hard to add, but i don't know how. That's why I need your help, please.. :(